# How can i optimse this part of code:

Tags: c++, class

I have class Complex, with defined friend Complex operators of +,-,*,/.

```
class Complex
{
private:
        float Re;
        float Im;

public:
        friend Complex operator + (const Complex ,const Complex );
        friend Complex operator * (const Complex ,const Complex );
        friend Complex operator - (const Complex ,const Complex );
        friend Complex operator / (const Complex ,const Complex );
};

Complex operator + (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{

    Complex c(0,0);
    c.Re=a.Re+b.Re;
    c.Im=a.Im+b.Im;
    return c;
}

Complex operator * (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    Complex c(0,0);
    c.Re=a.Re*b.Re;
    c.Im=a.Im*b.Im;
    return c;
}

Complex operator - (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    Complex c(0,0);
    c.Re=a.Re-b.Re;
    c.Im=a.Im-b.Im;
    return c;
}


Complex operator / (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    if(b.Im && b.Re)
    {
        Complex c(0,0);
        c.Re=a.Re/b.Re;
        c.Im=a.Im/b.Im;
        return c;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Cannot divide, one of parametars is zero."<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

What i want to optimse is instead of writing this all this so many times, and just changing the +,-,*,/ operator, i could write it once, and when in int main()
some of operators is beigned called(used) just read it and apply it to the function. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to define complex arithmetic this way? Usually, mathematicians don't define these like you do. Multiplication and division defined differently.

Comment: I suppose it could be done using macros, but that's almost never a good idea. Also, multiplication and division of complex numbers is not as simple as multiplication of real and imaginary parts.

Comment: You could extract the body of the operators to a generic "apply operator" function, and use lambda for each operator. You'll need to define each operator separately though, either through copy/paste, or with macros. There's no way around that other than using someone else's class.

Comment: yea i know its not definded like that, i just wanted to show you want i mean. I was thinking of some type of generic programming..

Comment: Since `Re` and `Im` are private, you should use public get and set functions to allow them to be accessed outside of the class. That way, you don't have to make everything a `friend`. `friend` should only be used when absolutely necessary, and you should prefer using the public interface..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Add this template function into `Complex`:

```
template <typename OP>
static Complex apply(const Complex a, const Complex b, OP op) {
    Complex c;
    c.Re = op(a.Re, b.Re);
    c.Im = op(a.Im, b.Im);
    return c;
}
```

Then the implementation of the operators is a little bit smaller:

```
Complex operator + (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    return Complex::apply(a, b, std::plus<float>());
}

Complex operator * (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    return Complex::apply(a, b, std::multiplies<float>());
}

Complex operator - (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    return Complex::apply(a, b, std::minus<float>());
}

Complex operator / (const Complex a,const Complex b)
{
    if(b.Im && b.Re)
    {
    return Complex::apply(a, b, std::divides<float>());
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Cannot divide, one of parametars is zero."<<std::endl;
        // Note: missing return value here
    }
}
```

Note: multiplication and division aren't defined like this for complex numbers.

Note2: I don't think this can be much smaller, as you must define the operators one by one, as far as I know (there is no trickery to define them at once, at least not in C++17).

Comment: Okay, il sort this out. Thank you